# Moving hg repo folder using copy-paste?

Tags: windows, mercurial

I have a hg repo on my local drive. I am new to hg and want to know if i can move the folder around freely. I am not talking about a folder under version control, i am talking about the folder that contains the repo it self.

I've found a lot of similar questions but most seem to be talking about a folder under version control. another answer is to use hg clone but i want to know if i can just cut and paste the whole repo.

I am using windows xp if that matters.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you can copy the repository itself by just copying the .hg folder.

Imagine the following folder structure:

```
MyRepo
MyRepo\.hg
MyRepo\file_under_version_control.txt
```

MyRepo is the whole repository (or as you called it, "folder under version control").

When you remove the .hg folder from it, MyRepo is just a normal folder without version control.

When you move the .hg folder somewhere else, you can create a new working directory by running [`hg update`](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/Update), so the new folder where .hg resides will be a complete repository again.

Comment: i think he means copying the directory containing the `.hg` directory.

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant as well. I just edited my answer to clarify!

Comment: beware! As I have been finding out recently, the contents of the `.hg` directory seem version-specific. You can't safely transfer a repo from Mercural version `X` and have it recognized by version `Y` on another system. For some years, that was working for me, but it seems like not these days (or I was getting lucky). Instead, use `hg bundle` to transfer repos like that.

Answer (score 2):

Technically you can, but you have two possibly unwanted outcomes if you do move your `.hg` folder:

1. There source folder no longer has hg repository in it. It just becomes a plain directory with files.
2. The destination folder suddenly has a (most likely) **totally unrelated** hg repository which you cannot really do anything meaningful with.

While the first outcome is no problem, the second likely is - unless the destination folder is just different working copy checked out from the same revision of your hg repository.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that is the whole idea behind [DVSC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributed_revision_control) (distributed version control systems), git also works in that way.